# Migrate to new component on clicking submit button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can anyone suggest how to migrate to new component on clicking submit button? I was making a simple login page using react.Included email field in  and a submit button, what m trying is if I enter email n click on submit the password component appears. i.e same as gmail login.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but if you just want two-steps login, then after submitting email change component state and render password input.

Comment: yeah I tried using states it worked but with some issues...also is there any way to set primary username and password?? for example i want to set it as abcd@xyz.com and password as 123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the main component as follows.

```
export default class Index extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentStep : 1,
    };
    this.changeStep = this.changeStep.bind(this);
}

loadSteps() {
    switch(this.state.currentStep) {
        case 1:
            return (<EmailView />);
        case 2:
            return  (<PasswordView />);
        default:
            return (<EmailView />);
    }
}

changeStep(step) {
    this.setState({ currentStep : step});
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="login-steps-container">
             {this.loadSteps()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

And Create two Child components for Email field and Password steps,

**Email.js**

```
export default class Email extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="email-step" >
            <input type="text" className="email-field">
            <input type="button" value="Go to" onClick="this.props.changeStep.bind(this, 2)">
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Password.js**

```
export default class Password extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="password-step" >
            <input type="password" className="password-field">
            <input type="button" value="Login" >
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: great! thanks... also can you please guide me in how to set primary test email and password...eg: i want email to work as abcd@xyz.com and password as 12345678

Comment: What do you mean by primary test email. Did you mean a placeholder text inside the textbox ? or a default email inside the textbox ?

Comment: I mean test email..i.e i want that the page to go further only if i enter abcd@xyz.com and password as 12345678

Comment: write an onClick event to the button of the Password.js file. Which event must be called to a function written in main component. ex:- See the `onClick` event bind in Email.js . There should be a authentication verification logic inside that method. I hope you can manage it.